# How to use testng arguments in Gradle useTestNG

Tags: java, gradle, testng, build.gradle

How to use the TestNG arguments mentioned in [TestNG arguments](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) in Gradle useTestNG plugin?

```
test {
   useTestNG {
       ..........
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use TestNG command line arguments you have to run it in Gradle like [JavaExec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).